# Active Vertex Group Selector

Tags: armature, vertex-groups

I'm working with a model that has a whoooolllleee bunch of vertex groups. I'm currently in the process adding new geometry to these groups. However, this is a crazy tedious process because the only way I know of how to change the active vertex group is by using this menu:

[image: set active vertex menu]

It would be sweet if the little box that pops up after I select a group would stick around:

[image: set active vertex group box]

So my question is: is there a piece of UI or something I can have that lets me quickly and easily change my active vertex group? Or maybe some way to keep that little box open?

Comment: as you must have seen, Ctrl G is the shortcut to choose the active group, then maybe create a shortcut for the Assign button to speed up the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended buying Vertex group Utils from the blender add on store. It's exactly what I needed and works well.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the active vertex group on the properties panel, in properties/data/vertex group-- select one of the vertex groups listed to make it the active vertex group.

If you have too many to scroll through, you can filter the list by name by clicking the arrow at the bottom of the list and typing in some text.  Here I'm filtering by "1":

[image]